# How to make an add button

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to add a button like this:

[image]

What I've tried is the following code:

```html
<ActionBar>
  <ButtonGroup>
    <Button type="action fa fa-plus"> Add New </Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ActionBar>
```

But the result doesn't look like I want, it is like in the following image. Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

*I saw that the text in the buttons is different, that's not important.*

Comment: <Button type="action" class="btnstyleclasshere"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New </Button>

Comment: Font-awesome gives you only images behind the text, but not the border

Comment: I would suggest for you to actually add the img to your button

Answer (score 2):

Please check below.

```css
button[type=action]:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: "\f067";
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

button[type=action] {
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ActionBar>
  <ButtonGroup>
    <Button type="action"> Add New </Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ActionBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some small changes on your example code. Loaded **Bootstrap** and **Font Awesome**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ActionBar>
  <ButtonGroup>
    <Button class="btn btn-default" type="action fa fa-plus"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New </Button>
    <Button class="btn btn-default" type="action"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search </Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ActionBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the font-awesome.css and it will make wonders for you. Check the below code using font-awesome and giving you the plus icon add button.

```css
button[type=action]:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: "\f067";
}

button[type=action] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ActionBar>
  <ButtonGroup>
    <Button type="action"> Add New </Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ActionBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button{
background-color:white;
border-color:lightgrey;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
padding:5px;
border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<ActionBar>
  <ButtonGroup>
    <Button type="action fa fa-plus"> &#10010; Add New </Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ActionBar>
```